# codeigniter no controller loads with database class on

Tags: database, codeigniter, controller

I have a live web server on AWS running ubuntu.
I use the codeigniter framework, however I have encountered a problem.
If I enable the database class with autoload library or from the controller itself, the page fails to display, and no errors given or logged. I tried using it on my own pages and even the "stock" codeigniter folder. I have found in the past that there usually is an error and which line, however, this scenario is bizarre, as I never have this problem on local web servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Don't forget to install the php mysql driver:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: Salf answer is perfectly fine. Please accept it as well.